# Call method on click on generated html component

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I'm pretty new in Blazor and I'm trying to create an HTML piece using RenderTreeBuilder.
This block is basically a div that should call a method when clicked and store its value in a variable.

```
AutocompleteListRender = builder =>
{
    builder.OpenElement(0, "div");
    builder.AddAttribute(0, "id", "input-autocomplete-list");
    builder.AddAttribute(0, "class", "autocomplete-items");

        foreach (string entry in Entries)
        {
            if (entry.ToLower().Contains(Value))
            {
                builder.OpenElement(1, "div");
                builder.AddAttribute(1, "id", entry + "-autocomplete-list");
                builder.AddAttribute(1, "onclick", /* Method to call */);
                builder.AddAttribute(1, "value", @entry);

                builder.AddContent(1, entry);

                builder.CloseElement();
            }
        }

        builder.CloseElement();
    };
```

The problem here is how to attach the event, since I cannot use @onclick here.
I would like to know what options I have here, since I have seen that it is possible to call events but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Unless you have a really good reason, it's recommended not to build components this way, but to stick to razor files. Especially if you are going to give every frame the same sequence as you showed here. Please see this gist from @SteveSandersonMS where they explain why this is bad. https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/ec232992c2446ab9a0059dd0fbc5d0c3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the [EventCallbackFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.eventcallbackfactory?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to invoke a method. Like this:

```
builder.AddAttribute(1, "onclick", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.Create<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.UIMouseEventArgs>(this, YourMethod));
```

and then define the method in the same class:

```
void YourMethod() {
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: @RamondeLlano Glad to hear.

Comment: @TimoSalomäki how can I pass a parameter to YourMethod?

Comment: @GuilhermeFlores There are overloads of the Create method with a single parameter Action, like [this one](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.eventcallbackfactory.create?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_EventCallbackFactory_Create__1_System_Object_System_Action_TValue__). If you're not familiar with Action delegates, you can take a look at [this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netframework-4.8) to get a feeling how the Action with one parameter can be passed within your Create method.